# Nest one array into another based on a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two arrays that I need to merge using JavaScript into one based on account number by nesting the 'members' under the 'main' account holder.

I have tried looping thru both and merging using the spread operator, but it ends up a spaghetti mess. This is one of my attempts.

```
  let merged = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    merged.push({
      ...array1[i],
      ...array2.find(itmInner => itmInner.acccountHolderStatus === array1[i].acccountHolderStatus)
    });
  }
```

Array 1:

```
[
  { accountNumber: "1111", firstName: "Jim", lastName: "Jacobs", accountHolderStatus: "main" },
  { accountNumber: "2222", firstName: "Sara", lastName: "Jones", accountHolderStatus: "main" },
  { accountNumber: "3333", firstName: "Alex", lastName: "Benson", accountHolderStatus: "main" }
]
```

and Array 2:

```
[
  { accountNumber: "1111", firstName: "Jesse", lastName: "Jacobs", accountHolderStatus: "member" },
  { accountNumber: "1111", firstName: "Pearl", lastName: "Jacobs", accountHolderStatus: "member" },
  { accountNumber: "2222", firstName: "Timothy", lastName: "Jones", accountHolderStatus: "member" },
  { accountNumber: "3333", firstName: "Belle", lastName: "Benson", accountHolderStatus: "member" },
  { accountNumber: "3333", firstName: "Chris", lastName: "Benson", accountHolderStatus: "member" }
]
```

I need the final array to look like this:

```
[
  {
    accountNumber: "1111",
    firstName: "Jim",
    lastName: "Jacobs",
    accountHolderStatus: "main",
    members: [
      { 
        accountNumber: "1111",
        firstName: "Jesse",
        lastName: "Jacobs",
        accountHolderStatus: "member"
      },
      {
        accountNumber: "1111",
        firstName: "Pearl",
        lastName: "Jacobs",
        accountHolderStatus: "member"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    accountNumber: "2222",
    firstName: "Sara",
    lastName: "Jones",
    accountHolderStatus: "main",
    members: [
      {
        accountNumber: "2222",
        firstName: "Timothy",
        lastName: "Jones",
        accountHolderStatus: "member"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    accountNumber: "3333",
    firstName: "Alex",
    lastName: "Benson",
    accountHolderStatus: "main",
    members: [
      {
        accountNumber: "3333",
        firstName: "Belle",
        lastName: "Benson",
        accountHolderStatus: "member" 
      },
      { 
        accountNumber: "3333", 
        firstName: "Chris", 
        lastName: "Benson", 
        accountHolderStatus: "member" 
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: _"I have tried..."_ - You forgot to show your approach.

Comment: In addition to @Andreas comment, Is there a condition based on which you want to push objects to members array. For ex: I see **lastName** as one key to compare.

Comment: Only push if there are 'member' objects with the same 'accountNumber' as a 'main' object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` the results into a new array using destructuring on your array1 and `filter` on the other to create the members key values. This doesn't change array1.

```js
var ar1 = [{accountNumber:"1111",firstName:"Jim",lastName:"Jacobs",accountHolderStatus:"main"},{accountNumber:"2222",firstName:"Sara",lastName:"Jones",accountHolderStatus:"main"},{accountNumber:"3333",firstName:"Alex",lastName:"Benson",accountHolderStatus:"main"}],
    ar2 = [{accountNumber:"1111",firstName:"Jesse",lastName:"Jacobs",accountHolderStatus:"member"},{accountNumber:"1111",firstName:"Pearl",lastName:"Jacobs",accountHolderStatus:"member"},{accountNumber:"2222",firstName:"Timothy",lastName:"Jones",accountHolderStatus:"member"},{accountNumber:"3333",firstName:"Belle",lastName:"Benson",accountHolderStatus:"member"},{accountNumber:"3333",firstName:"Chris",lastName:"Benson",accountHolderStatus:"member"}];

let res = ar1.map(v => ({...v, members: ar2.filter(e => e.accountNumber === v.accountNumber)}));

console.log(res);
```

The following won't create a member key if there are no members to be found:

```js
// In this snippet ar2 doesn't contain any object with "2222" as accountNumber
var ar1 = [{accountNumber:"1111",firstName:"Jim",lastName:"Jacobs",accountHolderStatus:"main"},{accountNumber:"2222",firstName:"Sara",lastName:"Jones",accountHolderStatus:"main"},{accountNumber:"3333",firstName:"Alex",lastName:"Benson",accountHolderStatus:"main"}],
    ar2 = [{accountNumber:"1111",firstName:"Jesse",lastName:"Jacobs",accountHolderStatus:"member"},{accountNumber:"1111",firstName:"Pearl",lastName:"Jacobs",accountHolderStatus:"member"},{accountNumber:"3333",firstName:"Belle",lastName:"Benson",accountHolderStatus:"member"},{accountNumber:"3333",firstName:"Chris",lastName:"Benson",accountHolderStatus:"member"}]

let res = ar1.map(v => ({...v, 
           ...(ar2.findIndex(q => 
                q.accountNumber === v.accountNumber) + 1 
                    ? {members: ar2.filter(e => e.accountNumber === v.accountNumber)} 
                    : {})}));

console.log(res);
```

```
...(ar2.findIndex(q => 
    q.accountNumber === v.accountNumber) + 1 
        ? {members: ar2.filter(e => e.accountNumber === v.accountNumber)} 
        : {})
```

The idea for this is as follows: We use the some logic as in our first code snippet but instead of adding `member` directly, we spread the result of a ternary operator. The operator checks whether we can find an index in array2 that holds the current accountNumber. If so we create an object that contains our member key as before (we spread it shortly afterwards again). If it doesn't contain any, findIndex returns -1. We add +1 to check for zero (which is falsy) so we get into the else part of our ternary. Our ternary then returns an empty object that gets spread afterwards and doesn't change anything.

Comment: thanks for this @assoron. Can you also show how to not add the 'members' empty ojbect if there are none for that 'main' account?

Comment: @mintwhip I added a solution for that, it's hard to read though. I add an explanation.

Comment: Wow, that is intense! Thx for that snippet and the explanation.

Comment: Honestly, for readability alone I'd rather use the first one and just check members for an empty array in other functions if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to only get the objects that belong to a specific account and assign it to the `members` key.

The fllowing code is all you need, in short: It loops through every account in `arr1` and then filters all the objects with the same account number in `arr2` and adds them to the `members` array.

```
arr1.forEach( account => {
        account.members = arr2.filter( a => a.accountNumber === account.accountNumber);
});
```

```js
arr1 = [
  { accountNumber: "1111", firstName: "Jim", lastName: "Jacobs", accountHolderStatus: "main" },
  { accountNumber: "2222", firstName: "Sara", lastName: "Jones", accountHolderStatus: "main" },
  { accountNumber: "3333", firstName: "Alex", lastName: "Benson", accountHolderStatus: "main" }
];

arr2 = [
  { accountNumber: "1111", firstName: "Jesse", lastName: "Jacobs", accountHolderStatus: "member" },
  { accountNumber: "1111", firstName: "Pearl", lastName: "Jacobs", accountHolderStatus: "member" },
  { accountNumber: "2222", firstName: "Timothy", lastName: "Jones", accountHolderStatus: "member" },
  { accountNumber: "3333", firstName: "Belle", lastName: "Benson", accountHolderStatus: "member" },
  { accountNumber: "3333", firstName: "Chris", lastName: "Benson", accountHolderStatus: "member" }
];



arr1.forEach( account => {
    account.members = arr2.filter( a => a.accountNumber === account.accountNumber);
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `map` and `filter`:

```
array1.forEach(parent => {
  array2.forEach(child => {
    if (parent.accountNumber === child.accountNumber) {
      if (!parent.members) {
        parent.members = []
      }
      parent.members.push(child)
    }
  })
})
```